# Why can't I log in to Cypress?

Tags: cypress, logout, auto

I am new to Cypress, I write different test cases in Cypress, my first case is that I want to login to the website, then do other activities. One thing in particular, in practice it should see the user login.

so i am expalin my case here,

1. before(function () { EITHER write login code here.....})  OR
2. create one case like it('Login',()=>{login code here.....})

then after create our required test cases after above IT block.
ex.

```
it('Login', ()=>{
//USER LOGIN CODE...
})
it('Dashboard', ()=>{
//Dashboard CODE...
})
it('Contact Us', ()=>{
//Contact Us CODE...
})
```

once the first case executes, the user can be logged in to the system, then after redirect on DASHBOARD, we click on the CONTACT US link/menu, and then the CONTACT US page is open where we can perform our operation.

Issue-
in my case, I had tried both the way before and separately IT block, every time if we click on CONTACT US page then redirect on Login page again.

and show the message on the log section-

-get#linkConactus > a
-click
-(new url)https://example.com/admin/dashboard
-(new url)https://example.com/login

---

This is my case-
I am confused Here i am sharing actual scenario with code.
///

```
describe('Dashboard Page', function () {
    it('login',function () {
       cy.visit('https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/');
        cy.get('#txtUsername').type('Admin');
        cy.get('#txtPassword').type('admin123');

        cy.get('#btnLogin').click();

        cy.get('#welcome').contains('Welcome');
    })
    it('Verify Dashboard Text', () => {
        cy.wait(2000);
        cy.log("this is Dashboard Page.............");

        let extText='Dashboard';
        cy.get('.head > h1').then((txt) =>{

                let act_txt=txt.text();
                cy.log('Actul Text is= '+ act_txt);
                expect(extText).to.eq(act_txt);
        })
    })
    it('My Leave Page', () => {
        cy.log('My Leave Page is Open..........')
        cy.get(':nth-child(5) > .quickLaunge > a > .quickLinkText').click();

//Issue facing on above line while I am click on next Menu like 'My Leave' then redirect to login Page.

        let extText='My Leave List';
        cy.contains('My Leave List').then((txt) =>{

                let act_txt=txt.text();
                cy.log('Actul Text is= '+ act_txt);
                expect(extText).to.eq(act_txt);
        })
        
    })
```

})

Comment: Cypress clears the [local storage, cookies, etc](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Is-resetting-the-state-necessary), between tests. Also, it is not good testing practice to inter test dependencies like you have above.

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess you don't have mocked all network requests correctly. Because a redirect to the login page should only happen, if the user is not authenticated. Maybe you webapp makes a network request, that fails and then redirects you to the login page.

Maybe try the following testing strategy, if you a newer. Because in Cypress you should always try to mock the network requests to your api with [cy.intercept](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept)

### Login page test

Create a seperate test file for this one.

You visit the login page, fill out the information and mock all request, that are made to your api with `cy.intercept`. Then press the login button. Now the test should login into your webapp without making any requests to your api.

### All other pages

Create a [cypress command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands) and name it like `mockLogin`. There you should setup all auth tokens in your local storage and mock the requests for validating this token. With that you can simulate as if the user is logged in and just revisits your webapp.
Now you can execute that command in every `beforeEach()` for your other pages. That way you are logged in in all of your tests, without manually loggin in for each test case.

Answer (score 0):

In Cypress version 12 a new change was introduced: by default testIsolation is true (see below) so if you have tests dependent of other tests, set that variable to false in your cypress.config file.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Test-Isolation